# hi i need a text box that must contain 8 digits only. the first 7 digits are numbers the last digit is a letter in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

hi i need a text box that must contain 8 characters only. the first 7 characters are digits while the last is a letter in VB.net i have tried it so many ways and this is the way i am currently trying it. at the moment it is giving the message not enough character thanks for any help.

```
    If txtStaffPPS.Text.Length <> 8 Then
        MsgBox("staff pps must be 8 characters long")
    ElseIf Not Char.IsDigit(First7Char) Then
        MsgBox("numbers are wrong")
    Else
        If Not Char.IsLetter(LastChar) Then
            MsgBox("last digit is wrong")
        Else
            MsgBox("text is accepted")
        End If



    End If
    '  End If
```

Comment: Try `If txtStaffPPS.Text.Length <> 8 Then`

Comment: thanks for reply tried that and it is still giving message "staff pps must be 8 characters long"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask].  Where that code is located might be useful to know.

Comment: You could use a MaskedTextBox instead of a TextBox. Set the Mask property to "0000000L" to only allow 7 decimal digits followed by a letter. Before doing something with the Text property, check that the MaskCompleted property is True (meaning all 8 characters have been entered).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
    Dim CharList As New List(Of Char)
    CharList = txtStaffPPS.Text.ToCharArray
    If CharList.Count <> 8 Then
        MsgBox("staff pps must be 8 characters long")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 to 6
        If Char.IsNumber(CharList.Item(i)) = False Then
            MsgBox("numbers are wrong")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    If Char.IsLetter(CharList.Item(7)) = True Then
        MsgBox("text is accepted")
    End If
```

Comment: You might also want to check that Char.IsLetter(CharList(7)) = True.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into System.Text.RegularExpressions?

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtStaffPPS.Text, "^[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]{1}$")
```

This will return either "True" or "False". I believe it will check for the first seven being digits, the last being a letter(special characters aren't included) and if text <> ' it will also return false.

You won't specifically be able to pinpoint where the user when wrong, but you could pop up a general message indicating the correct format.

One way you could possible pinpoint where a user went wrong is to use multiple regular expressions.

```
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "^.{8}$") Then
        MsgBox("Staff pps must be 8 characters long")
    ElseIf Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "^[0-9]{7}") Then
        MsgBox("The first seven digits must be numbers")
    ElseIf Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "^[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]{1}$") Then
        MsgBox("The last character must be a letter")
    Else
        MsgBox("Text Accepted")
    End If
```

Maybe clean it up a bit, but this should work.